# SQL insert using stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers, cursor

I am fighting an error which is stopping my stored procedure from working:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL  server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (SELECTED_PROJECT_LOBSELECTION = 'Copy the Whole Project') THEN SET lob' at line 1:"

Here is a portion of my IF/ELSEIF statement:

```
    IF (SELECTED_PROJECT_LOBSELECTION = 'Copy the Whole Project') THEN
  SET lobInsertStmt = ' AND p.PROJECTION_PROJECT_NME = ' || SELECTED_PROJECT_NAME
                   || ' AND p.PROJECTION_PROJ_CATG_NME = ' || SELECTED_PROJECT_CATG
                   || ' AND p.FINANCIAL_PROJECTION_YEAR_NUM = ' || CAST(SELECTED_PROJECT_YEAR AS int)
                   || ' AND g.MODEL_GROUP_SNAPSHOT_TSP = ' || SELECTED_SNAPSHOT_TIMESTAMP;
```

What am I doing incorrectly and why won't my compare work? Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**
My issue wasn't an IF/THEN compare. It was how the IN params were being read. Here is the solution to that:

```
IF (SELECTED_PROJECT_LOBSELECTION = 'Copy the Whole Project') THEN
  SET lobInsertStmt = ' AND p.PROJECTION_PROJECT_NME = ''' || SELECTED_PROJECT_NAME || ''''
                   || ' AND p.PROJECTION_PROJ_CATG_NME = ''' || SELECTED_PROJECT_CATG || ''''
                   || ' AND p.FINANCIAL_PROJECTION_YEAR_NUM = ' || TRIM(CAST(SELECTED_PROJECT_YEAR AS int))
                   || ' AND g.MODEL_GROUP_SNAPSHOT_TSP = ''' || SELECTED_SNAPSHOT_TIMESTAMP || '''';
```

Now, I am receiving an SQLSTATE of 07005 which is: "The cursor 'cursor-name' could not be used as specified because the prepared statement named in the declaration for the cursor was not a SELECT statement."

How can I do the insert with a stored procedure without the cursor?

Here is additional code:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE "SCHEMA"."PROCEDURE_NAME" (
    IN "SELECTED_PROJECT_NAME" VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET LATIN,
    IN "SELECTED_PROJECT_CATG" VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET LATIN,
    IN "SELECTED_PROJECT_YEAR" VARCHAR(4) CHARACTER SET LATIN,
    IN "SELECTED_SNAPSHOT_TIMESTAMP" VARCHAR(28) CHARACTER SET LATIN,
    IN "SELECTED_PROJECT_TYPE" VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET LATIN,
    IN "SELECTED_PROJECT_LOBSELECTION" VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET LATIN,
    IN "SELECTED_LOB_NUMBERS" VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET LATIN,
    IN "COPY_TO_PROJECT_NAME" VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET LATIN,
    IN "REQUESTER_ID" VARCHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN,
    OUT "TEST_OUT" VARCHAR(5000) CHARACTER SET LATIN,
    OUT "SQLSTATE_OUT" VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN,
    OUT "SQLCODE_OUT" INTEGER)
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN

DECLARE lobInsertStmt varchar(500);
DECLARE mystmt varchar(5000);

DECLARE CURSOR_C CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR PREPSTMT;

 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 

 BEGIN
      SET SQLCODE_OUT = SQLCODE;
      SET SQLSTATE_OUT = SQLSTATE;
      SET TEST_OUT = mystmt;
 END;


 IF (SELECTED_PROJECT_LOBSELECTION = 'Copy the Whole Project') THEN
  SET lobInsertStmt = ' AND p.PROJECTION_PROJECT_NME = ''' || SELECTED_PROJECT_NAME || ''''
                   || ' AND p.PROJECTION_PROJ_CATG_NME = ''' || SELECTED_PROJECT_CATG || ''''
                   || ' AND p.FINANCIAL_PROJECTION_YEAR_NUM = ' || TRIM(CAST(SELECTED_PROJECT_YEAR AS int))
                   || ' AND g.MODEL_GROUP_SNAPSHOT_TSP = ''' || SELECTED_SNAPSHOT_TIMESTAMP || ''''; 
-- Other ElseIFs
END IF;
SET mystmt = 'INSERT INTO D_FAR_WORK_VW.V_COPY_MODEL_PROCESS_WORK' 
            || ' SELECT  reqt.RUN_ID,''' 
            || SELECTED_PROJECT_NAME || ''' AS TO_PROJECTION_PROJECT_NME,'
            || ' m.PROJECTION_MODEL_SEQ_ID,'
            || ' m.PROJECTION_MODEL_ROW_SEQ_ID,'
            || ' p.PROJECTION_PROJECT_NME as FROM_PROJECTION_PROJECT_NME, ''' 
-- More insert code
PREPARE PREPSTMT FROM mystmt;

OPEN CURSOR_C;

SET TEST_OUT = mystmt;
SET SQLSTATE_OUT = SQLSTATE;
SET SQLCODE_OUT = SQLCODE;
END P1;
```

Comment: You have to run this code in a trigger or procedure.

Comment: Can you post the remainder of the SQL associated with this? Dynamic SQL will need to be processed within a stored procedure (or maybe a trigger).

Comment: Your error message indicates you're using MySQL, why do you tag [Teradata]?

Comment: I am creating the Stored Procedure to work in the teradata environment. I did receive help and it turned out my problem wasn't a compare after all. It was more of how the IN values were being read.  I am having an issue with it executing now, I might need a trigger (SQLSTATE 07005).  I will post more of the code, but leave out the code that may give away my database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my question.  I removed the cursor and added an execute statement

```
EXECUTE PREPSTMT;
```

after the Prepare